# ExpandableListView within a ListView

Tags: android

Is it possible to have an ExpandableListView within a ListView in android? I only need one item on the list to expand.

Comment: use onclick view gone and visible for that particular list item.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you display one or more items in listview. But there are more items for example 100 items in listview then you can use load more button in listview which display more items when user click on it. I think you refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/).